# PHP Exec Shell Returns ASCII UTF8 Needed/Intended

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, exec

**Short version:**

`/usr/local/bin/aws s3 ls s3://bucketlocation/folder --recursive` from shell gives

```
file - 复件(1).tiff
```

where as from PHP (`shell_exec()` or `exec()` same result) I receive:

```
file - ??(1).tiff
```

**Detailed version:**

I'm not able to retrieve data correctly from AWS because the shell functions appear to be using ASCII for the character encoding returns.

If I run shell command directly I get back Chinese characters as intended. Any PHP usage of the same commands malforms the Chinese characters because ASCII doesn't have these characters. I know the issue but not how to solve it.

My php.ini has:

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

I've tried:

```
php -r "shell_exec('LANG=en_US.utf-8 && /usr/local/bin/aws s3 ls s3://bucketlocation/folder --recursive');"
```

also tried:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
```

and

```
header('Content-Type: charset=utf-8');
```

(initially when first thought issue was at browser level)

If I use `mb_detect_encoding` I get back `ASCII`.

`exec` has the same behavior as `shell_exec` so there must be some setting for the PHP shell to convert encoding... but I'm not seeing it in any manual entries or on any threads.

Comment: Why use `shell_exec()` for this sort of thing when there's a perfectly good [PHP SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) maintained directly by Amazon?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Does the usage matter? Going into why we're using the functions we are would be long and off topic. SDK is nice but it's an XY solution. Next time I want to use shell and run into UTF8 chars I'll have the same issue. I need to know the cause, not a work around.

Comment: You need to pay attention to the encoding the file system uses... some might use utf-8, but some don't

Comment: Have you tried other commands and/or services, just to see if it is specific to this? I made a quick file on my server with a Unicode filename and Unicode contents that you can test with `php -r "echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/curl -s https://vendiadvertising.com/.txt');"`. You should get back `Chris loves !!!` if that works correctly.

Comment: Printing out the raw bytes subjects them to the encoding vagaries of whatever you're using to display the strings, and copy/pasting those displayed strings further subjects them to a trip through the browser and into StackOverflow which is just more levels of potential munge. Use `bin2hex()` or `hexdump` on those filenames and show use what _those_ return, then we might be able to make some more applicable suggestions.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I do get `Chris loves !!!` when running that... so I guess it is not entirely the shell.

Comment: @Sammitch Running `php -r "echo '复件';"`. Not sure how I can run `bin2hex` on it because it appears the malformation occurs in the `exec` process. Running `php -r "echo bin2hex('复件');"` gives me `e5a48de4bbb6`. Copying the characters from the CLI response and from the AWS console returns the same hex values. (CLI response being when I manually execute the command, `/usr/local/bin/aws s3 ls s3://bucketlocation/folder --recursive`)

Comment: @HonkderHase When running `echo $LANG` I get back `en_US.UTF-8`. Is that the correct command to view the file systems character set?

Comment: Also consider [using `putenv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#78279) and edit your Q to (of course) give us one full example on what you really do.